# How to get count for each day between certain times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a total count for each day between 07:00 and 19:00 for the last 7 days.  The below query only displays the count for the date 7 days back and not each individual day. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 7, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
DECLARE @Date2 AS DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 19, CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME))

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), DATE, 120) AS Report_Date, COUNT(DISTINCT GUID) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, +270, DATE) >= @Date
AND DATEADD(MINUTE, +270, DATE) < @Date2
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), DATE, 120)
```

Comment: see if you can share the structure of the table and a bit of sample content. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need past past 7days so  use getdate()- 7

```
SELECT CAST(DATE as DATE) AS Report_Date,
           COUNT(DISTINCT GUID) AS ROW_COUNT
    FROM t 
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) >= 7 AND
          DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) < 19
          and CAST(DATE as DATE)>=getdate()-7 and CAST(DATE as DATE)<=getdate()
    GROUP BY CAST(DATE as DATE)
    ORDER BY CAST(DATE as DTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert date columns to dates.  Use date functions. I don't understand why you are adding 270  minutes to the date.

I would go for a more direct answer to your question:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE as DATE) AS Report_Date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT GUID) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) >= 7 AND
      DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) < 19
GROUP BY CAST(DATE as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(DATE as DTE)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
;With T AS
(
    SELECT CAST(DATE as DATE) AS Report_Date,COUNT(DISTINCT GUID) AS ROW_COUNT
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE 
    DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) >= 7 AND     DATEPART(HOUR, DATE) < 19
)
SELECT Report_date,Row_Count From T GROUP BY Report_date
ORDER BY Report_date
```